# GORM, one class has both many-to-one and many-to-many (needs two belongsTo)

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In my class I need to do something like below:

```
class Category {

    static hasMany = [subCategories: Category, contracts: Contract]

    static belongsTo = [parentCategory: Category]    
}
```

Which mean I need two belongsTo, however for

```
  static belongsTo = [parentCategory: Category]
```

, it's OK, but for Contract many-to-many mapping, I need to write something like this:

```
 static belongsTo = Contract
```

there is some problem. How can I write them in the same line?

Can I write something like this:

```
static belongsTo = [parentCategory: Category, contract: Contract]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you have the correct syntax. You know, you could have just tested that yourself.

Comment: I tried, it seems doesn't work. It has some errors like: Error loading plugin manager: No owner defined between domain classes [class Contract] and [Category] in a many-to-many relationship. Example: static belongsTo = Category (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)